# Can a method in a generic abstract base class "know" the most-derived class of its instance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible:

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
    public void MyFunc() { ... }
}

public MyClass : A<string>
{
}
```

Is there a way for *MyFunc* to know that it has been instanced in a clas  of type *MyClass* ?

---

I think I need to clarify the question some more:
I have a generic abstract class that contains some core functionality accessed through a singleton.

The user is building a derived class to extend functionalities but the class is not instantiated through a new, but rather by the singleton, contained in the A class once it is accessed.

So, you could see the flow as such:

```
In the beginning, there is the abstract A<T>
The user creates MyClass : A<string>
The user now accesses: MyClass.MyFunc()
The singleton in MyFunc is then creating the instance
```

The singleton code is as follows:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> _Instance = new Lazy<T>(CreateInstanceOfT);
    protected static T Instance => _Instance.Value;
    private static T CreateInstanceOfT()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
    }
}
```

so:

```
class A<T>
```

is really:

```
class A<T> : Singleton<A>
```

but what I really need is to, somehow, make it like

```
Singleton<MyClass>
```

or whatever class is deriving from

```
A<T>
```

I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Why does the method need to know it has been instantiated? (Or, alternatively: what do you mean by "know"?)

Comment: It can refer to `T`, and figure out that `typeof(T)` is `string` - is that enough?

Comment: I'm creating a singleton and I need to call Activator.CreateInstance, so it's not T (the string) I need) but I need to know if I can find that this specific instance is part of a class of type A

Comment: tbh, if `T` can be anything it might be a little tricky to access it's properties or methods (you need to cast it). the best example `T` can be anything is just like in `Collections`.

Comment: *I need to call `Activator.CreateInstance`* -- it is possible, [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314431(v=vs.113).aspx) @Thomas, look for `return Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>(); `

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do something like:

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
    public void MyFunc() 
    {
        if(this.GetType() == typeof(MyClass))
        {
            // do your magic
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : A<string>
{
}
```

*but why?*

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, if I read your question right, that if the instance of A needs to have MyFunc act differently when it is a MyClass, then MyFunc should be virtual, and overridden in MyClass.

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
    public virtual void MyFunc() { ... }
}

public MyClass : A<string>
{
    public override void MyFunc() { ... }
}
```